# git status in git worktrees show HEAD, ORIG_HEAD, COMMIT_EDITMSG, logs

Tags: git, git-worktree

When working with git worktrees and I do git status in one of the checked out branches I see stuff like `HEAD, FETCH_HEAD, index.lock, ORIG_HEAD, commondir, gitdir, index, COMMIT_EDITMSG, logs/`

**REPREX**

```
$ git clone --bare https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife
$ cd Spoon-Knife.git
$ git worktree add -B main worktrees/main main
$ cd worktrees/main
$ git status
On branch main
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        HEAD
        ORIG_HEAD
        commondir
        gitdir
        index
        logs/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Shouldn't this files be hidden from git status? Am I doing something wrong?

**Workaround:** I added them to `myrepo.git\info\exclude` but it feels I shouldn't have to do that.

**Note:** git version 2.43.0.windows.1

Comment: Do not create work trees in bare repositories. The bare repositories are supposed to be used on servers, not to work on them (i.e. the only operations they are involved on are `fetch` and `push`). Use regular repositories (`git clone` **without** `--bare`) to work. A regular repository already has a work tree.

Comment: 1) I created a worktree inside a bare repo to keep all checkouts inside one folder, but I realized I got in trouble just because of that.

Comment: 2) `-B`  right, I souldn't have used it for this example, with or without the flag my problem was the same, lack of understanding that I should not create worktrees inside a bare repo. It would have been great if git warned me about that though.

Comment: 3) Do not create work trees in bare repositories. Lesson learned, thanks.
"bare repositories are supposed to be used on servers", I think it's ok to use them on a computer too, my main problem was to create worktrees inside the bare repo instead of elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git worktree` stores metainformation about worktrees in a subdirectory named `worktrees`. You're very much advised to not overuse the subdirectory to store your real worktrees. Use a different name (also not clashed with other Git internals like `modules` or `objects`). Anything like this:

```bash
$ git worktree add _worktrees/main main
$ git worktree add worktrees_/main main
$ git worktree add ../worktrees/main main
```

The last one is the best IMO. Do not put anything into Git-managed subdirectories.

Comment: Hmm I was unlike when I chose a name where to place all checkouts.
I could have chosen the following instead `git worktree add -B main mycheckouts/main main` but probably as you said the last option is better. Thanks!